# Are there any specific plans for France to shut/restrict its Schengen borders during the 2024 Summer Olympics?

Tags: schengen, france, event-based-effects, olympics

While Schengen borders are generally open, countries have the right to shut/restrict their borders with other Schengen countries in certain scenarios.

Has France announced any plans to temporarily reintroduce controls or otherwise restrict entry from other Schengen countries during the 2024 Summer Olympics?

Even is nothing is announced, is there any precedent for similar events within the Schengen zone that make it a possibility?

Comment: Basic police security measures can be done anywhere inside a country. Done randomly it would also be far more effective than at well known border points. Disrupting the cross border commuters would probably cause more damage than benefits. So for security measure planers, border controls is probably a less attractive option.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Not really. The issue is in the vast majority of countries, law enforcement has more powers at the border than domestically, specifically, to search and detain people and goods.

Comment: @user71659 Do not worry, if required the law enforcement will have the needed authority they require.

Comment: @user71659 "in the vast majority of countries, law enforcement has more powers at the border than domestically": in the context of this question, I rather suspect that the issue is whether France is one of those countries.  If they reintroduce border controls, they can screen everyone crossing the border.  If they have the power to set up a perimeter around areas where the Olympics are taking place and screen everyone entering those areas, that could be rather more efficient as it would require screening far fewer people.

Comment: @MarkJohnson And yet France has regularly done just that but arguably racial profiling and targeting certain means of transportations make that more tolerable for those commuters whose comfort matters.

Comment: @user71659 and Rich The question is essentially moot for a few separate reasons : (1) France is regularly renewing its border control notification, cf. guillaume31's answer, (2) regular (and arguably illegal) checks were already a regular occurence before that, (3) police powers, including practically unrestricted “random” checks or searches without any probable cause, are already very extensive in France compared to neighbouring countries (4) the *préfets* have very extensive powers to impose additional restrictions for special events or any other “risk to the public order”

Comment: (5) courts have been very shy about using their powers to oversee police action in general and especially when there is a crisis (including the *gilet jaune* protests or last year's riots) and (6) the Interior minister has already signalled its intent to use all these powers to their fullest extent including by speaking about “harassing and cleaning criminality by any means available” and saying that he “believes that Paris will never have seen so many [law enforcement officers]”.

Comment: In this context, I don't know if the border will be a priority but I don't think the niceties of EU law on border checks mean much.

Comment: For the most part these checks are of little impact: EU citizens and legal immigrants pass them quickly, illegal immigrants get some degree of harassment but France barely deports anyone to their home country in practice. So it's all security theater.

Comment: @JonathanReez You regularly use comments to bring up vaguely related right wing nonsense, where do you even get this stuff? It's gone down since the beginning of the Covid pandemic but the number of people removed from France has otherwise steadily increased over the last decade, peak was 18000 people in 2018, more than 10000 last year. The state is not forthcoming with comprehensive statistics but this policy costs over €500M per year. How is that “barely anyone” and how many people do you think should be removed and at what cost?

Comment: Obviously *nobody* get deported at the border, that's a completely different category. What happens at the border is that you either get refused entry (another 10000 people a year for France but it's relatively rare compared to other countries because mainland France does not have land borders with non-Schengen countries) or bounced illegally (certainly not tracked by official stats but actually quite common, I don't know how anyone can pretend to know it impacts barely anyone).

Comment: It should be noted French customs have the authority to check anyone anywhere in the country (though in practice, checks happen at points of entry or as a result of tips/investigation), regardless of the situation at the border.

Answer (score 9):

France among other EU countries has been using Schengen exception clauses to reinstate interior border controls since the 2015 terrorist attacks, and circumventing/overusing them ever since in a continuous series of extension periods.

In 2022 and 2023, the EU court of Justice [ruled](https://curia.europa.eu/jcms/upload/docs/application/pdf/2022-04/cp220064en.pdf) that these controls could not be made to exceed 6 months in that way unless a new, different serious threat arised.

France's Conseil d'Etat has however ruled against the ECJ since, and French majority politicians have lobbied to loosen the Schengen regulations. In February 2024 an [agreement](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/press/press-releases/2024/02/06/schengen-council-and-european-parliament-agree-to-update-eu-s-borders-code/) has been reached between EU Council and Parliament to extend the periods to a maximum of two years, renewable for a year.

The new rules will take time to finalize and implement. In the meantime, France [currently](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/schengen-area/temporary-reintroduction-border-control_en) has temporary reintroduction of border control running until April 2024 due to new terrorist threats, and is likely to renew it again for the Olympics even if there wasn't a specific annoucement about it. That means yes, expect border controls on entry where border police sees fit, especially when travelling [by air](https://www.lefigaro.fr/voyages/nouveaux-controles-aux-frontieres-nbsp-cacophonie-a-l-aeroport-20201001) through airports that have the infrastructure to host a customs check (it even happens in unlikely routes like Belgium -> France for instance).

Comment: Belgium => France is a very big roadway for various illicit substances (notably from the Netherlands), this is no wonder

Comment: Well it is by no means a terrorist threat, and as mentioned in the linked Figaro article, unlike air, road and rail were (are?) left surprisingly unchecked.

Answer (score 8):

It is very likely it will renew the controls reintroduction, since those have been [reintroduced](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/document/download/11934a69-6a45-4842-af94-18400fd274b7_en?filename=Full%20list%20of%20MS%20notifications_en_1.pdf) since 2015 :

> Foreseeable cases (Article 25 and 26 of the codified SBC)
>
> For foreseeable events (e.g. sports events), the duration of the border control is limited to 30 days or for the foreseeable duration of the threat, if it exceeds 30 days.

> Even is nothing is announced, is there any precedent for similar events within the Schengen zone that make it a possibility?

Except for the above, the European Football cup 2016, which was held in France, had no other specific measures

Comment: I have downvoted this answer because I do not understand what it is saying